# Azure website deployment to machine that already has a "Default web site"

Tags: iis, azure-devops

I am trying to deploy a website via Azure Devops to an IIS server that has the "Default Web Site" started with a binding on port 80.

I want my website to run on port 80.

I am using the "IIS Web App Manage" task. When I run my deployment on this machine, I get an error:

> [error]Binding (http / * : 80 : ) already exists for a different website ("site "default web site" (id:1,bindings:http/*:80:,state:stopped)"), change the port and retry the operation.

I have stopped the default web site but I still get the same error because the binding already exists.

I have tried using the IIS Web App Manage task to remove the binding on the Default web site but there does not appear to be a way to do this.  I do not see another task that will perform this task.

I am trying to automate this for future deployment via Azure Devops so I do not have to change the bindings or remove the default website by hand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am trying to automate this for future deployment via Azure Devops so I do not have to change the bindings or remove the default website by hand.

Based on my experience, you could add `Run PowerShell on Target Machines` task before `IIS Web App Manage` task with following script

```
Get-WebBinding -Port 80 -Name "Default Web Site" | Remove-WebBinding
```

[image]