# Binding (172.XX.X.XX : 1433 : MyServerName) already exists for a different website, change the port and retry the operation

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-devops, network-programming, azure-pipelines

In my Azure DevOps release pipeline, I want to simultaneously publish a website and a database.

I'm having trouble publishing the DB, for the simple reason that on a different pipeline, for a different website, I'm already addressing that same database: same IP, and the same Port (1433).

The error message is:

> Binding (172.XX.X.XX : 1433 : MyServerName) already exists for a different website,
>   change the port and retry the operation

There is a similar thread on Stackoverflow:

[Similar thread but the problem is on IIS (not SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54446426/azure-website-deployment-to-machine-that-already-has-a-default-web-site)

I understand perfectly that we cannot deploy 2 websites on the same IP on the same PORT on IIS, **but why does Azure Devops prevent me from deploying 2 databases on the same IP on the same PORT (1433 - SQL Server standard) ?** It doesn't make sense.

I am using the first pipeline task (red):

[image]

**Should I use the green ones?** Unlike the first, they're not Microsoft standards, they're open-source.

I would like to remember that I didn't have any trouble publishing the first website. The problem only appeared when I targeted the same database server (same IP/Port) in the second website release pipeline.

Comment: What does your pipeline look like? Share the full logs of the failing step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it. Those 3 parameters:

> 172.XX.X.XX : 1433 : MyServerName

Turn out to be a key that must be unique. In fact, the HostName, where I put 'MyServerName', is **not the machine name**. It is the domain name for the website and **you can call it whatever you please except any name already taken by other application.**

**I used the ServerName, as I did in the first website. I can't:**

[image: Use a new HostName, not an existing one]

That's why I had the error. Now it's OK!